# Booking Calendar Data Presentation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, calendar

I am developing a booking calendar and I want to represent the availability of cabins by time slots as below.

[image]

And display a combined "availability" view of all the cabins as below:

[image]

What would be the best table structure in order to represent this requirement. and how can I query the database to get my final overall availability screen? Can i get the intended output in one query?

Or any proposals to represent the overall availability of cabins in a better way than above is most welcome.

Your suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you could represent booked as 0 and free as 1, and then for column availability you sum the values given weigh for each column, so that cabin A has weight 1, cabin B has weight 2, cabin C, has weight 4, cabin D has weight 8 and so on. So in the case of cabins A & B free the sum will be 3. Coverting the number of avalilabity in base 2 you know who cabins are free

Answer (score 1):

A simple structure might be as follows:

```
cabins
(cabin_id*
,cabin_name)

bookings
(booking_id*
,cabin_id
,from_datetime
,to_datetime)

* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```